# ASP .NET Core : Directory.EnumerateFiles and IIS hosting

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-2.0, absolute-path

When I publish my ASP .NET Core (v.2.2) web application on a IIS-server it throws an exception on this line:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(_environment.ContentRootPath + @"/Pages/API")
```

The exception:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Release\MySite\Pages\API'.
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException at
>   System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String
>   path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)

When I look inside the published folder there is no API folder, but should it not be inside of my website dll? Or can I not use relative or absolute paths to find files in my web project when I publish it on ISS?

Note: The pages in folder API have Build Action : content, and the code works without problem in development (with IIS-express).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For asp.net core, it will precompile views while publishing into Project.Views.dll. For `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, it only lists the real exist files in the disk.

For a solution, try to modify your project.csproj to add `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>`.

Full

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>


<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```